# Carrying intent from PreferenceActivity to LWP Service/Movie class

Tags: java, android

I am having trouble carrying over a user selected image/gif to the main LWP service. I start off by prompting the user to select a gif through this PreferenceActivity (some of this was borrowed from members here and tutorials on Vogella)

```
public class GifPreference extends PreferenceActivity implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener{

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    //SharedPreferences SHARED_PREF;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName("custom_gif");
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefsettings);  
        getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(
                this);

        getPreferenceManager().findPreference("custom_gif").setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener()
        {
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference)
            {
                Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
                int width = display.getWidth();
                int height = display.getHeight();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Select a GIF - " + (width) + " x " + height , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI); 
                photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);
                return true;
            }
        });

    }




    public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {          
        String [] proj={MediaColumns.DATA};  
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery( contentUri,  
                proj, // Which columns to return  
                null,       // WHERE clause; which rows to return (all rows)  
                null,       // WHERE clause selection arguments (none)  
                null); // Order-by clause (ascending by name)  
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);  
        cursor.moveToFirst();  
        return cursor.getString(column_index);}


    @Override 
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 
    if (requestCode == 1) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) { 
      Uri selectedImage = data.getData();   
      String RealPath;
      SharedPreferences customSharedPreference = getSharedPreferences("custom_gif", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = customSharedPreference.edit ();
      RealPath = getRealPathFromURI (selectedImage);
      editor.putString("custom_gif", RealPath); 
      editor.commit(); 
      ComponentName component = new ComponentName(getPackageName(), getPackageName() + ".LWPEngine");
      Intent intent = new Intent(WallpaperManager.ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER);
      intent.putExtra(WallpaperManager.EXTRA_LIVE_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT, component);    
      startActivity(intent);

    }}

}
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().
           unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
            String key) {
    }

}
```

And this is the main LWPService:

```
public class LWPEngine extends WallpaperService {
    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE1 = 1;
    static final Handler mGIFHandler = new Handler();
    //public String gifBG;



    public Engine onCreateEngine() {
        try {
            LWPEngine.GIFEngine var1 = new LWPEngine.GIFEngine();
            return var1;
        } catch (IOException var3) {
            return null;
        }


    }

    class GIFEngine extends Engine {

        private LWPEngineHelper lWPEngineHelper = new LWPEngineHelper(LWPEngine.this.getApplicationContext(), LWPEngine.this.getResources());
        private final Movie mGIF;
        private final int mGIFDuration;
        private final int mGIFHeight;
        private final Runnable mGIFRunnable;
        private final int mGIFWidth;
        private String mImageScale = "Stretch to screen";
        private long mStart;
        private int mWhen;


        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public GIFEngine() throws IOException {
            //decodes and plays the gif - if no gif is found, throw an error.
            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(LWPEngine.this);

            String gifBG = prefs.getString("custom_gif", "This file does not work");
            InputStream var2 = new FileInputStream(gifBG);

            //InputStream var2 = LWPEngine.this.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.dogegif);


            if(var2 != null) {

                try {
                    this.mGIF = Movie.decodeStream(var2);
                    this.mGIFDuration = this.mGIF.duration();
                } finally {
                    var2.close();
                }


                this.mGIFWidth = this.mGIF.width();
                this.mGIFHeight = this.mGIF.height();
                this.mWhen = -1;
                this.mGIFRunnable = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        GIFEngine.this.animGIF();
                    }
                };
            } else {
                throw new IOException("Can't open GIF");
            }
        }

        void animGIF()
        {
            tick();
            SurfaceHolder localSurfaceHolder = getSurfaceHolder();
            Canvas localCanvas = null;
            /*      try
      {*/
            localCanvas = localSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            if (localCanvas != null)
                animGIFDraw(localCanvas);
            if (localCanvas != null)
                localSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(localCanvas);
            LWPEngine.mGIFHandler.removeCallbacks(this.mGIFRunnable);
            if (isVisible())
                LWPEngine.mGIFHandler.postDelayed(this.mGIFRunnable, 40L);
            return;
            /*      }
      finally
      {
        if (localCanvas != null)
          localSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(localCanvas);
      }*/
        }

        void animGIFDraw(Canvas var1) {
            this.lWPEngineHelper.setBackground(var1);
            var1.save();
            PointF var3 = this.lWPEngineHelper.getCanvasScale(this.mImageScale, this.mGIFWidth, this.mGIFHeight);
            var1.scale(var3.x, var3.y);
            this.mGIF.setTime(this.mWhen);
            Point var5 = this.lWPEngineHelper.getImagePos(var3, this.mGIFWidth, this.mGIFHeight);
            this.mGIF.draw(var1, (float)var5.x, (float)var5.y);
            var1.restore();
        }

        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            LWPEngine.mGIFHandler.removeCallbacks(this.mGIFRunnable);
        }

        public void onOffsetsChanged(float var1, float var2, float var3, float var4, int var5, int var6) {
            super.onOffsetsChanged(var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6);
            this.animGIF();
        }

        public void onSurfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder var1, int var2, int var3, int var4) {
            super.onSurfaceChanged(var1, var2, var3, var4);
            this.animGIF();
        }

        public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean var1) {
            super.onVisibilityChanged(var1);
            if(var1) {
                this.animGIF();
            } else {
                LWPEngine.mGIFHandler.removeCallbacks(this.mGIFRunnable);
            }
        }
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs,
                String key) {
            String gifBG = prefs.getString("custom_gif", "This file does not work");
            //gifBG = prefs.getString("custom_gif", "Bad Image");
        }
        void tick() {
            if((long)this.mWhen == -1L) {
                this.mWhen = 0;
                this.mStart = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            } else {
                if(this.mGIFDuration!=0) {
                    this.mWhen = (int)((SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - this.mStart) % (long)this.mGIFDuration);                
                }

            }
        }



    }


}
```

I keep getting a null pointer exception - I'm guess because there's nothing there - so I'm obviously not setting the shared preferences right - or it's the inputstream...

Any help in getting a user selected image to the inputstream of the main LWPservice would be very helpful!

**Edit I should mention everything works up until I start the LWPService after selecting the GIF. It's when loading the lwp I get the error. using a static GIF in the drawable does work.

Thanks in advanced, 
Marc

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer in case anyone is curious.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(LWPEngine.this);

            String gifBG = prefs.getString("custom_gif", "This file does not work");
```

needs to be:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("custom_gif",MODE_PRIVATE);

            String gifBG = prefs.getString("custom_gif", "This file does not work");
```

Also needed to change this in my SharedPreference class as well.

getSharedPreference needs context, and the way I had it before for was limiting the scope of the "global" capabilities of the SharedPreference method.

I hope that helps people!